# Prove the orthogonal complement is equal to the orthogonal complement of the Span.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v_1, \dots, v_m \in V$. Prove that $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}^{\perp} = (span(v_1, \dots, v_m))^{\perp}$.

What I tried to do is say suppose $v \in V$ such that $v = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_mv_m$ so v is in the span above. Then if you take the orthogonal complement of this.....? I'm not sure how to do this can someone give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: To show two sets are equal, show each is a subset of the other.  What is $V$?

Comment: I guess I'm confused on what the orthogonal complement of $v \in V$ is exactly when working with a linear combination like this since I'm used to working with sets. Like the set of vectors orthogonal to v would be all vectors in V such that the dot product is zero but I don't know how to use that to prove subsets, do you think you could shed some light on it?

Comment: What is $V$? ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to prove that $A = B$ for some sets $A,B$, you need to show that $x \in A \implies x \in B$ and that $x \in B \implies x \in A$ (i.e. any element of one set is also an element of the other set).

For this question, you need to show the following two things:

1. $x \in \{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}^{\perp} \implies x \in (\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_m))^{\perp}$
2. $x \in (\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_m))^{\perp} \implies x \in \{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}^{\perp}$.

Remember that $x \in \{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}^{\perp}$ means that $x$ is orthogonal to $v_1, \ldots v_m$, which is equivalent to $x \cdot v_1 = \cdots = x \cdot v_m = 0$. Also, $x \in (\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_m))^{\perp}$ means that $x$ is orthogonal to any element of $\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$, i.e. $x \cdot (a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_mv_m) = 0$ for any real numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_m$.

Comment: So for the last part can I choose scalars $a_1, \dots a_m$ all equal to one to show part 2? Or can I just say that the a's are irrelevant since for dot product you have homogeneity in the first/second slot (meaning you can just kind of distribute out the a's anyway)?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to look at it is that if $x \in (\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_m))^{\perp}$, then $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$, which includes $v_1,\ldots,v_m$.

Answer (score 0):

By bi linearity of the inner product you can see that $x\in V^{\perp}$ iff $1\leq \forall i\leq m$ ,  $x\perp v_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a subset of $V$. Then $S^{\perp}$ is the set (vector subspace) of vectors that are orthogonal to $S$.

Now it should be clear that $S^{\perp} \subseteq span(S^{\perp})$. Can you show the reverse direction by using the above definition of $S^{\perp}$?

It might be better to do for S= $\{v_1,v_2\}$ first, just to get clear ideas.